# Error message occurs when mouseover(play video) and mouseout(stop video and reload video)

Tags: jquery, video, mouseover, mouseout

Error message in chrome console:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'currentTime' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The element's readyState is HAVE_NOTHING.

This is my code used to test mouseover videoplay and mouseout video stop reload:

```
<video poster="http://corrupt-system.de/assets/media/sintel/sintel-trailer.jpg" 
  src="http://corrupt-system.de/assets/media/sintel/sintel-trailer.m4v" id="id1" 
  width="150" onMouseOver="id1.play()" title="hover to watch video 1" ">
</video>

<script>
  $('#id1').mouseout(function(){
  var video1 = document.getElementById("id1");
  video1.pause();
  video1.currentTime = 0;
  video1.load();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for Your editing , looks nicer.

Comment: the thing is when i use pure html video tag and js trigger , this error occurs, but if i switch to framework such as video.js, such error message won't appear.